unreliable firebase notifications via subscriptions - flutter
I have a flutter app and node, django backends. I am using Firebase to send notifications to the flutter app (on both iOS and Android).
The regular push notifications (via the registration token) seem to be working as expected.
The problem is with subscriptions.
On the flutter app,
Future<void> addFirebaseSubscriptions() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic("all");
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic("test");
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic("android-version");
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic("ios-version");

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("all");
    logger.i('[Topics] Subscribed to topic: all');
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("test");
    logger.i('[Topics] Subscribed to topic: test');

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("android-version");
      logger.i('[Topics] Subscribed to topic: android-version');
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("ios-version");
      logger.i('[Topics] Subscribed to topic: ios-version');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    logger.e('[Topics] Error subscribing to topics: $e');
  }
}


Future<void> main() async {
...
// init firebase app
// setup notifications
await addFirebaseSubscriptions();
// FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen
// FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage
// FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen
...
}

on the server side (in node), i do something like:
if (getApps().length === 0) {
    initializeApp({
        credential: cert(JSON.parse(serviceAccount))
    })
}

const message = {
    notification: {
        title,
        body,
    },
    data: notificationData || {},
    topic: target,
}

console.log('Sending notification:', message)

const response = await getMessaging().send(message)

console.log('Successfully sent notification:', response)

I even get the console logs saying "Successfully sent notification: messageId"
BUT some phones never receive the messages at all.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app as well.
Another weird thing is a version of the app that was released to production, suddenly stopped receiving notifications via subscriptions for a day (tested on my own personal iPhone) and then today, with literally no changes to anything in the entire architecture, started receiving notifications!
Problem

Some phones don't receive notifications (both android and iOS) while some phones with the same version of the app and OS do
Some phones, which were receiving notifications, randomly stop receiving notifications.

Please help! Is there something I am doing wrong?

Since I just discovered this myself - if you have access to a problematic device, you can use this for troubleshooting: https://x.com/puf/status/1854539490984915295
